# How to get characters separated by space using scanf

Tags: c, input, scanf

Here is `input.txt`

```
5
A B C D E
```

I want to get these characters so I used this code:

```
//...
int n;
fscanf(fp_i, "%d", &n);
//...
char data;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fscanf(fp_i, "%c", &data);
    array_c[i] = data;
}
//...
```

There were still spaces in `array_c`, so I tried `" %c "`, and it worked!

I want to learn of another way to get characters with spaces. Is there a more sophisticated way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine the way you have it, the only improvement I would suggest it to read directly to the array instead of an intermediate variable `data`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fscanf(fp_i, " %c ", &array_c[i]);
}
```

Note that for `array_c` to be treated as a string it should have 6 elements, being the 6th element a null-terminator.

You would have:

```
//...
int n;
fscanf(fp_i, "%d", &n);
char array_c[n + 1];
//...
for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
    fscanf(fp_i, " %c", &array_c[i]);
}
array_c[n] = '\0';
//...
```

[**Running sample**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OE5O1ajybL7dAfaS)

Comment: Generally you do *not* want a trailing space -- it will not do anything useful, and while it might not hurt, it can cause unexpected hangs with interactive input.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, yes, it's of no use. Removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional space in front of `%c` should work.

```
int n;
fscanf(fp_i, "%d", &n);

char data;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fscanf(fp_i, " %c", &data); // space front of %c
    array_c[i] = data;
}
```